# yii2 quote escape method

Tags: php, yii2

I have a blog where I can add posts, so let's say I created a tag called `asd'qwe`

then I create a post, add a tag via search, enter `asd'`, and when it comes to the quote `'` I get an error in the network

> SQLSTATE[42000]: Syntax error or access violation: 1064 You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near ''asd'', `name`)' at line 1 The SQL being executed was: SELECT `id`, `name` FROM `blog_tag` WHERE `name` LIKE '%asd\'%' ORDER BY LOCATE('asd'', `name`)

it's all because of this quote here, here is my function for adding a tag to a post

```
public function actionGetTags($query = '')
    {
        Yii::$app->response->format = Response::FORMAT_JSON;

        if (!is_string($query) || !$query) {
            return '';
        }

        $tags = BlogTag::find()
            ->select(['id', 'name'])
            ->where(['like', 'name', $query])
            ->orderBy(["LOCATE('$query', `name`)" => SORT_ASC])
            ->asArray()->all();

        return $tags;
    }
```

I heard in yii2 there are escaping methods to fix a similar error, but I have not yet figured out where and how to use it

I will be grateful for any help or hint.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you call `orderBy` like that, the value of $query is inserted into the string before it's passed into `orderBy` function. The `orderBy` function treats the array keys as column names and it won't escape them.

That's quite a problem because beside the error you are experiencing it can be abused for SQL Injection attacks.

If you want to use more complex expressions in your `order by` clause of SQL query you should use `yii\db\Expression`. That will allow you to pass `$query` as bind param instead of including it directly.

In your case the `orderBy()` can look like this:

```php
->orderBy(new \yii\db\Expression(
    'LOCATE(:query, `name`) ASC',
    [':query' => $query]
))
```

You don't have to worry about the `where()` call. For simple conditions like `['like', 'name', $query]` the query builder will use the bind params automatically.